# Width UIButton auto layout

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints

[image]

I want the "Connexion" button to be of the same aspect ratio of what it looks on the image but I don't figure it out. With all that I read on auto layout on the web I got very confused with it.

If someone can explain to me what constraints I have to add to have this result and most importantly **why** ?

Comment: can you explain a bit more how large you want the button to be depending on the size of the view?

Comment: @AndreSlotta Horizontally I want the same ratio of occupancy between the button and spaces on both side of it and if it is possible to adjust the height size of the button in function of that to keep the same ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope i got you right. in storyboard set up the following constraints:

1. ctrl drag from the button DOWNWARDS to the main view, release and choose **vertical spacing to bottom layout guide**
2. ctrl drag from the button (direction does not matter in this case) to the main view, release and choose **equal widths**
3. ctrl drag from the button UPWARDS to the main view, release and choose **center horizontally in container**
4. ctrl drag from the button to the button itself, release and choose **aspect ratio**

after that select the button and go to the **size inspector**. click the **edit** button next to the **equal width** constraint and set the **multiplier** to **0.5**.

then click the **edit** button next to the **ratio** constraint and adjust the **multiplier** to fit your needs (e.g. the value **3:1** means that the button's width is three times the button's height / the button's height is a third of the button's width).

good luck.

Answer (score -1):

Auto Layout is used to get the elements to resize themselves according to screen size. Although I found it not helping in friendly way. What You want to do to obtain the desired result is :
1. uncheck auto-Resize, and Layouts.
2. in attributes inspector, change size of view to freeform.
3. the next button to that of attributes inspector Yoy will find some red lines. Add constraints you want to add. I am attaching image of that.
This might answer your question.

[image]